# After one hot encoding, instead of columns, my number of rows are increasing

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, categorical-data

This is the code:

```
housing_cat1 = X_train[:,[2,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,35,39,40,41,42,53,55,57,58,60,63,64,65,73,74,78,79]].reshape(1,-1)

from future_encoders import OneHotEncoder

cat_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)                  # Set to True if sparse matrix is needed
housing_cat_1_1hot = cat_encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat)
housing_cat_1_1hot
```

Answer (score 1):

[get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function of pandas can also be used for this. Just create a pandas dataframe with your data and subject it to this function. There is no need to list categorical variables:

```
X_train_df = pandas.DataFrame(data=X_train)
X_train_df_1hot = pandas.get_dummies(X_train_df)
```

You can specify prefix etc also for new columns is required:

```
pandas.get_dummies(data, prefix=None, prefix_sep='_', 
     dummy_na=False, columns=None, 
     sparse=False, drop_first=False, 
     dtype=None)
```

Data as a list of lists is available with `.values` attribute which can be converted to a numpy array:

```
housing_cat_1hot = numpy.array(X_train_df_1hot.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the shape of housing_cat1, and what is the shape of housing_cat_1hot?

You shouldn't be reshaping to (1, -1). This takes all the data and puts it in one long row.